# glmmADMB residual plot and regression estimates

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, residuals, glmm

I am running a GLMM using the package glmmADMB. My data is zero-inflated and has a negative binomial distribution. I have some questions about some of the figures that are produce from the model:

1- When checking for heteroskedasticity, the following plot is produced. I am unsure how to interpret if this is ok or not. The points seem reasonably evenly distributed but there also seems to be a pattern forming on the bottom half. It looks like at certain levels of the predictors, there is a relationship to the variance of the response. Is this a correct interpretation? If there is heteroskedasticity, is there a way to account for this/change this?
[image: Residual Plot]

2- In the regression estimate (using coefplot2) I am interpreting any variable that does not cross the centre y-axis as being significant. Can someone explain what the smaller, darker lines in the middle of the bars mean? Is this some sort of quartile measure? In addition, is it possible to get my intercept value on this figure? The value of my intercept is meaningful (takes the value of one my categorical variables (time11)) and I would like to include it on this figure.
[image: Regression Estimates]

Thanks in advance!

Kirsten

Answer (score 1):

Your residual plot suggests that your outcome has a moderate number of possible values. Hint: where do the apparent straight lines come from?

Does the documentation not tell you what the thicker lines are? Presumably they join the lower and upper quartile.